# Why are villagers not growing when I am away ? MINECRAFT PC 1.12.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Got myself a village farm, but the villagers in it aren't growing unless I am in the immediate area of the farm. Say I go straight mining and come back , they still little babies and I need to afk on the rooftop in order to get them to grow.

What is causing this and will OPEN LAN solve the issue?

I am on survival singleplayer FYI

Comment: Can you imagine how many resources your computer would need in order to keep the whole world loaded? Only visible chunks are "alive". And, no, making a server won't help.

Comment: I know how resource demanding it would be, but how about only keeping track of the villagers for example. Only the important stuff I guess :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft worlds are almost infinite in size. You can walk millions of blocks in one direction and there's still more to come. Minecraft does a lot of things in every loaded chunk all the time and there is just no way to have such giant worlds and having all of it loaded all at once. That's the reason why Minecraft loads the worlds in [chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk).
One chunk is a 16x16 area from the bottom of the world (height 0) to the maximum build height (height 255). The chunks around you are always loaded, but only up to a certain distance from you. You can control how far this distance is with the slider "Render distance" in the video settings. You can try it out and observe how the distance you can view changes with it. But unless you have a really powerful computer, you will notice a significant performance decrease when you set the limit high.
If you go farther than that distance away from the village, the chunks are no longer loaded and time will pretty much freeze for that area. Villagers won't grow up, water won't flow, redstone machines will pause.

<s>There are ways to keep any chunk loaded that you want, but that affects performance and is complicated to do. But there is a certain area in any Minecraft world that is always loaded: The [spawn chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk). Those are the chunks around the place where you originally spawned in the world. You can find the location of them for your world using tools like [this one](http://chunkbase.com/apps/spawn-chunks-reader). You can then either move your villagers there or, if you're really lucky, there might even be a village there already.</s>
This part does no longer apply to 1.14. Chunk loading is very broken in that version, so you need a player around to load chunks properly.

So, in summary:

- If your mine is closer than 512 blocks to the village, you can try turning up your render distance. But if your PC isn't powerful enough, the game could become like a slide-show or even freeze completely.
- <s>You can move the villagers to the spawn chunks.</s>
- Or you can stay in the area.

(P.S.: No, the game can not only load the most important things. Even if you only consider 0,0001% of the world important, that's still 14062500 chunks to be loaded, that's 3328 times as much as what would currently be loaded with the most computationally intense setting.)

Comment: cool man, OP AF i thought the minecraft world had a limit based on the seed like 1000 chunks or whatever. Cuzz I have seen people reach the end of their map and they just cant dig thru the blocks so I figured its not infinite.
So If I change my spawn location to the village for example or just move them to my current spawn (I did change it after I left my old house) they gon be active forever. Or does this rule apply to the first ever spawn ?

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov Not your "spawn location", server's spawn.

Comment: Only the first ever spawn. You can change that, but it requires commands ("cheats"). And yes, there is a limit, just not after 1000 chunks, but after 1875000 chunks.

Comment: So I just move the villagers to my second spawn and they gon be active for all eternity, or until I move again, correct?

Comment: What second spawn? Only the initial spawn where you appeared the very first time in this world counts. You can use the tool I linked to find it. (http://chunkbase.com/apps/spawn-chunks-reader)

Comment: Riiiiiight, so the place where I first spawned, I know where it is I can get to it, alright then thanks for the info it was very useful!

Comment: No. I have to tell you that the spawn chunks reader gives me the area around my SECOND house, the one that I had changed my spawn using cheats/commands manually.So I need to move the village farm again since I moved them to my first house.... well at least I know my spawn active chunks :D

PS:  The villager farm isnt working right now, even though its on the original spawn of the map.

Comment: I didn't know you used commands in that world. `/setworldspawn` moves the world spawn point and with it the spawn chunks. But the spawn chunk finder I linked you to should still give you the correct result, because it reads it from your save file.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say this whole time :D never mind I'm gonna move the villager farm again :D